# Interaction between soy milk and coffee producing bubbles

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I noticed when I poured my soy milk (which I shook as per the directions on the carton) into my coffee, a large number of very fine bubbles rose to the surface. What causes this? Is there a chemical reaction involved, or is it just a physical effect?

Comment: I can't see here any reaction. Probably it were just bubbles of air - shaking could mix milk with air a little.

Comment: @Mithoron the bubbles were very fine when I did it almost like effervescence